# Setting (and/or deleting) State information on Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, stateful

I am trying to learn more about Stateful widgets in Flutter. I am following online courses but it is expected that the examples provided are not as complex just yet. I am trying to build a page wherein I inject a PRODUCT class from a Listview.builder index from the previous page.

```
class Product extends Merchant{
  String productname;
  String productimage;
  double price;
  bool productwishlist;
  List<Drinks> drinks;
  List<Addon> addons;


  Product({@required this.productname,@required this.productimage,@required this.price, @required this.productwishlist, this.addons, this.drinks});
```

In this ProductDetails page, I have a stateful widget that does the following:

1. Injects the Product price from the index and multiplies it based on the amount stored from a counter
2. Shows a list of drinks and addons that respond to a tap through a GestureDetector. The gesture detector also updates the list to show a selection indicator.

My current challenge is that everything works fine when I work only with the Product amount and the counter. For some reason, everytime I click an addon or a drink with a price of 0, it still updates and adds something on top of the total cost, which should stay the same. Please help a noob like me move forward lol

Here's the full code for the ProductDetail page

```
class ProductDetails extends StatefulWidget {

  Product product;
  ProductDetails({this.product});
  int amount=0;
  double productcost=0;
  double drinkcost = 0;
  double addoncost = 0;
  double totalcost = 0;

  @override
  ProductDetailsState createState()=>ProductDetailsState();


}

class ProductDetailsState extends State<ProductDetails>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Addon> addonlist = widget.product.addons;
    List<Drinks> drinklist = widget.product.drinks;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.black,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            ListView(
              children: [
                Stack(
                  children:[
                    Stack(
                      children: [
                        ClipPath(
                          clipper: OvalBottomBorderClipper(),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 150,
                            color: mintgreen,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Positioned.fill(
                          child: ClipPath(
                            clipper: OvalBottomBorderClipper(),
                            child: Container(
                              height: 150,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    begin: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                    end: Alignment.topLeft,
                                    colors: [Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                                      Colors.transparent]),),
                            ),),),],),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: IconButton(onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          }, icon: Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Colors.black,
                              size: 25)),),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: widget.product.productwishlist?
                          IconButton(onPressed: () {},
                              icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.favorite, color: Colors.black, size: 25))
                              :
                          IconButton(onPressed: () {},
                              icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.favorite_outline, color: Colors.black,
                                  size: 25)),)
                      ],
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                      child: Center(
                        child: ClipOval(
                            child: Container(height: 225,width: 225,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('images/'+(widget.product.productimage)),fit: BoxFit.cover)),),),),),
                  ]),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15,20,15,0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(widget.product.productname, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontFamily: 'Nunito', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white)),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                          color: mintgreen,
                          boxShadow: [BoxShadow(blurRadius: 5, offset: Offset.zero, color: Colors.white)]),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            GestureDetector(
                                onTap: widget.amount>0?(){
                                  setState(() {
                                    widget.amount--;
                                    widget.productcost=widget.product.price * widget.amount;
                                    widget.totalcost = widget.productcost+widget.drinkcost+widget.addoncost;
                                  });
                                }:null,
                                child: Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline, size: 30, color: Colors.black,)),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:5, right: 5),
                              child: Text(widget.amount.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                            ),
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: widget.amount<20?(){
                                setState(() {
                                  widget.amount++;
                                  widget.productcost = widget.product.price * widget.amount;
                                  widget.totalcost = widget.productcost + widget.drinkcost + widget.addoncost;
                                });
                              }:null,
                                child: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline, size: 30, color: Colors.black,)),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )



                    ],),),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15,15,15,0),
                  child: Text(widget.product.price.toStringAsFixed(2), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontFamily: 'Nunito', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white)),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15,40,15,0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text("Select Drink", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontFamily: 'Nunito', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white)),
                      ],),),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15,15,15,0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 150,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: black,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)
                    ),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: widget.product.drinks.length,
                        itemBuilder: (_,index){
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            setState(() {
                              widget.product.drinks.forEach((Drinks drink) {
                                drink.isSelected = widget.product.drinks[index] == drink;
                                widget.drinkcost = drink.drinkprice * widget.amount;
                                widget.totalcost = widget.productcost+widget.drinkcost+widget.addoncost;
                              });
                            });
                          },
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border: widget.product.drinks[index].isSelected ?
                                      Border.all(color: mintgreen, width: 5):null,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                      boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                                      color: mintgreen,
                                      offset: Offset(1, 1),
                                      blurRadius: 10,)
                                      ]
                                    ),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Image.asset("images/${drinklist[index].drinkimage}", height: 60, width: 60,),
                                  ),),
                                SizedBox(height: 5,),
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(drinklist[index].drinkname, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontFamily: 'Nunito'),),],),
                                Text(drinklist[index].drinkprice.toStringAsFixed(2), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontFamily: 'Nunito'),),

                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15,15,15,0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text("Select Add Ons", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontFamily: 'Nunito', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white)),
                    ],),),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15,15,15,0),
                  child: Container(
                      height: 150,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: black,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)
                      ),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemCount: widget.product.addons.length,
                          itemBuilder: (_,index){
                            return GestureDetector(
                              onTap: (){
                                setState(() {
                                  widget.product.addons.forEach((Addon addon){
                                    addon.isSelected = widget.product.addons[index] == addon;
                                    widget.addoncost = widget.amount * addon.addonprice;
                                    widget.totalcost = widget.productcost+widget.drinkcost+widget.addoncost;
                                  });
                                });
                              },
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          border: widget.product.addons[index].isSelected ?
                                          Border.all(color: mintgreen, width: 5):
                                          null,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                          boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                                            color: mintgreen,
                                            offset: Offset(1, 1),
                                            blurRadius: 10,)
                                          ]
                                      ),
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                        child: Image.asset("images/${addonlist[index].addonimage}", height: 60, width: 60,),
                                      ),),
                                    SizedBox(height: 5,),
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Text(addonlist[index].addonname, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontFamily: 'Nunito'),),],),
                                    Text(addonlist[index].addonprice.toStringAsFixed(2), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontFamily: 'Nunito'),),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    ),),
                SizedBox(height: 100,)
                ]),

          ],
        ),
        ),
    bottomNavigationBar:

      GestureDetector(
        onTap: widget.amount == 0? (){
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }:null,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.black,
          child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15,15,15,15),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  height: 60,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    color: mintgreen,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      widget.amount==0?
                      Text("Back to List",style: TextStyle(color: black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20, fontFamily: 'Nunito')):

                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text("Add to Cart: ", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20, fontFamily: 'Nunito'),),
                          Text(widget.totalcost.toStringAsFixed(2), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20, fontFamily: 'Nunito'),),
                        ],
                      ),

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned.fill(
                child: Container(
                  height: 60,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                          begin: Alignment.bottomRight,
                          end: Alignment.topLeft,
                          colors: [Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                            Colors.transparent])
                  ),),
              ),
            ],
          ),
    ),
        ),
      ),

    );
```

Comment: Can you upload the code on GitHub so that I can get more clear view? There are some missing model class here.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).